# how to prevent page header stop jumping on window scroll

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a fixed header, which gives me a big headache for last 4 hours googling here, that slightly jumps from right to left once page start loading. how to prevent this and have fixed header on link clicks. here is my css:

```
<div id="main-header" style="border: none; width: 100%; margin: auto; top: 0; z-index: 100; background-color: #9A430B;"> 
  the links are here...  
  </div>
```

thanks in advance

here is the script that keeps it on top,...

```
 <script>
 $(document).ready(function() {

var div = $('#main-header');
var start = $(div).offset().top;

$.event.add(window, "scroll", function() {
    var p = $(window).scrollTop();
    $(div).css('position',((p)>start) ? 'fixed' : 'static');
    $(div).css('top',((p)>start) ? '0px' : '');
  });

});
 </script>
```

but the links are slightly jump from right to left on clicks, on page load,...

Comment: Where does jQuery come in here?

Comment: I'm not sure, that kind of slight variation happens by vertical scroll. If I am correct, then change the width.

Comment: It may be "preparing" for a possible vertical scroll to appear.

Comment: Do you have a link that shows this happening?  Also, you say a 'fixed' header but I don't see any `position: fixed`.

Comment: yes exactly,... it is preparing scrolling, when it start loading it stops. I have seen some sites where headers are fixed like a glue and not jump when page loading,...

Comment: yes it is position fixed,... ok let me put the fixed script to it,...

Answer (score 1):

Try this [**Demo**](http://jsbin.com/UJohibUT/2/edit) css styling for a change. I have given `position:fixed` if you want your header to remain at fixed position even if user scroll the page.

Your header will probably be jumping because of the layers. i.e. your header must be on top of your html structure as they appear in . I do not know if you want any fixed header or not. But if you do not want it to be fixed then you do not need to specify any position, just give

```
width:100%;
z-index:5; //just a higher value than 1
```

**Note:** do not set `floating` or `position:absolute` unless it is necessary. plus you do not need JavaScript to set styling for your header, it can be easily maintained with CSS without any complexity. Hope I am clear with this response.